# Model termination error in modelica (end line error of a model)

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am new to modelica and tried to formulate an equation in Dymola using a new model. However, I ended up with errors related to end line of model. I could not figure it out.
Could you please help me out.
Thanks in advance.
For the reference, I have attached description of 2 image files.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest to post code as text in the future, not as image.

Comment: As a newbie to Modelica, I would recommend you check out these two sources: https://mbe.modelica.university/ and https://webref.modelica.university/. Welcome to the wonderful world of Modelica.

Comment: https://mbe.modelica.university/components/packages/nimport/

Answer (score 2):

The equation (`j = j_0*{...}`) needs a semicolon at the end;

Comment: There are some more things that need to be changed, like {} and [], these are for arrays. Also, you should not define constants that are already defined in MSL constants. You should not use reals with units as comment or description string, but use types with units.

Comment: In the next version of Dymola the error message will be clearer that semicolon is missing. The errors of using [] for function call and {} as parenthesis should be detected later.

Comment: @HansOlsson When would the next version be released?

Comment: Sometime later this year according to plan. The detailed plan is not official as far as I know.